# Is it possible let emacs has function like 010 editor file format analyzing?

Tags: emacs, hex, reverse-engineering

Recently, I do some reverse engineering, But I can't find the hex editor like 010 editor in Linux.
I heard the emacs can customizing a lot of thing via lisp. I wonder if emacs can have 010 editor 
template function. If it can I decide to learn emacs with lisp.

Comment: This might not have been true at the time the question was asked, but currently 010 Editor is available for linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs is not your tool of choice for this. It is not the best for everything (although we all try). hexl-mode is nice but if you try to open a really large file or a disk image or the like things will go down hill quickly.

You are better off helping improve existing open source hex editors and there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the 010 editor, so I can't judge whether Emacs's support for hex editing is anywhere near comparable (Emacs's hex editing mode is not particularly sophisticated), but you can try it with `M-x hexl-mode RET`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to explore binary files on Linux, you can give a try with [hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home). It is a a library written in python that can help to retrieve and browse internal file structures, plus several viewer applications built upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can open very large file now with [VLF minor mode](https://github.com/m00natic/vlfi).

Answer (score 0):

Emacs does have some support for decoding binary data but its a bit more manual than 010 editor - see [bindat](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Packing.html#Byte-Packing) in the emacs manual.

Basically you describe a template for your data and then use elisp to decode it so you need to do some basic elisp coding but the example shown at the bottom of that page should get you started.